# change boxBackgroundColor of TextInputLayout for android.support.design.widget

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

I want to change dynamically `boxBackgroundColor` of TextInputLayout when **`editText.setEnables(false)`** .
I've tried to do this via res/color/selector_input_background_color but it didn't work. Also `TextInputLayout` (`android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`) doesn't have such parameter as `boxBackgroundColor` ! ;( - it's ONLY preset in AndroidX library (`com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`), that I'm afraid to migrate to right now. (Old project)

here is how my layout look like

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        [...]
        android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutTheme"
        style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
             [...]
             />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

TIL inherit styles from new MaterialDesign

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/selector_input_background_color</item>
</style>
```

And depending on state I provided selector inside res/color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#00FF00"/>
    <item android:color="@color/editTextBackground"/>
</selector>
```

I'm afraid this is a bug, because Google promise to keep compability with 28.0.0 support library version and AndroidX. What's funny even if TextInputLayout doesn't have method such as `.setBoxBackgroundColor` it works inside style - but selector doesn't.

I suspect due to this gap, even if I have selector boxBackgroundColor it is not called when EditText change `state:enabled`, because TextInputLayout don't know that parameter - however it somehow magically used at the begin when the layout is loaded.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. It's a bug. Selector is not working. You have to do it programiatically.

Comment: A ticket is open on their tracker for this issue, we'll have to wait :)

Comment: I created it as I remember

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is only workaround for it.

You can use **support** library as long as You want to keep the same box color all the time.

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/selector_input_background_color</item>
</style>
```

However if You want to change its color (e.g that indicated that field is disabled), You have to change it programatically. But there is one hitch. You have to switch to **androidX**, because in android.support there is lack of this method.

So You have to do

```
textInputLayoutPhone.setBoxBackgroundColorResource(R.color.editTextDisableBackground);
```